# Drupal 7 IMCE image paths

Tags: 7, files

I develop sites on my server then move them when ready. I just started using [IMCE](https://drupal.org/project/imce) and everything works well other than the image path. For instance:

The path shows */test/sites/default/files/images/test.png* however I want */sites/default/files/images/test.png* so when I move the site I don't have to redo all the images.

I set the rewrite in the `.hataccess` file and I set the base url in `settings.php`. Is there something else I need to set?

Answer (score 2):

If you develop your site in a sub folder, rather than a subdomain, you are going to be in for a bad time. All of your image paths and links are going to be incorrect. You are better of moving to a subdomain instead. If its already too late then use the [Pathologic](https://drupal.org/project/pathologic) module to clean them up.

> Pathologic is an input filter which can correct paths in links and
>   images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise
>   cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or
>   the content was moved to a different server. Pathologic can also solve
>   the problem of missing images and broken links in your site’s RSS
>   feeds.